# angular service not returning data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I am a newbee in angular and in a web project i implementing service for the first time and I am having problem:

```js
var app = angular.module("mdmapp", ['ui.router']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('creafund', {
            url: '/creafund',
            templateUrl: '/mdm/html/fundtype.html'
        })
        .state('creareceipt', {
            url: '/creareceipt',
            templateUrl: '/mdm/html/receipttype.html'
        })
        .state('fundentry', {
            url: '/fundentry',
            templateUrl: '/mdm/html/fundentry.html'
        })
        .state('payentry', {
            url: '/payentry',
            templateUrl: '/mdm/html/payentry.html'
        })
        .state('reports', {
            url: '/reports',
            templateUrl: '/mdm/html/reports.html'
        });

});


app.service('DataServer', function ($rootScope, $http) {

    //this function is to get the list of fund types.
    this.GetFundType = function () {
        $http.get('/mdm/server/app.php/GetFundType')
            .then(function (response) {
                return response;
            });
    };
});

//controllers for the various pages and sections.

app.controller('mainctrl', function ($scope, DataServer) {
    $scope.FundTypeList = DataServer.GetFundType();
});

app.controller('ftctrl', function ($scope, $http, DataServer) {

    $scope.SaveFundType = function () {
        var data = {desc: $scope.ftdesc};
        $http.post('/mdm/server/app.php/FundTypeCreate', data).success(
            function (data, status, headers) {
                $scope.ftdesc = null;
                $scope.FundTypeList = DataServer.GetFundType();
            }
        );
    };
});
```

in upper mention code i am unable to get data from 'datasever' service, it is fetching json response from a rest api...will render a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait for the promise in the controller like this:

```
function Factory($http) {
    var service = {
      GetFundType: GetFundType
    };

    return service;

    function GetFundType() {
        return $http.get('/mdm/server/app.php/GetFundType');
    }
}

function Controller1($scope,Factory) {
  Factory.GetFundType().then(function(response) {
    $scope.FundTypeList = response.data;
  });
}
```